# Returning a subset of types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, dependent-type, liquid-haskell

I'm trying to restrict the return type of a function to a subset of (kind) constructors. I can use [typeclasses](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3u03ce/define_a_subset_of_constructors_of_an_adt_as_a/cxaxoxb) to restrict the input types, but when I try the same technique on return types as shown below, I get a `Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘'A’` error.

Is there a way to restrict the `bar` function below to return either `SomeA` or `SomeB`?

It seems that Liquid Haskell is an alternative, but it seems that this should be possible using only things like `DataKinds`, `GADTs` and/or `TypeInType`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module Test where

data State = A | B | C

class AorB (s :: State)
instance AorB 'A
instance AorB 'B

data Some (s :: State) where
  SomeA :: Some 'A
  SomeB :: Some 'B
  SomeC :: Some 'C

-- This works
foo :: AorB s => Some s -> Bool
foo aorb = case aorb of
  SomeA -> True
  SomeB -> False

-- This fails to compile with ""Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘'A’""
bar :: AorB s => Some s
bar = SomeA
```

Comment: `bar` is incorrect, because if the caller chooses `s` to be `B` (which satisfies the constraint `AorB`) then the implementation `SomeA` is not valid.   Does that help guide your thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things here.  If you compile with `-Wall` *(which you should!)* you would find that your definition of `foo` gives an inexhaustive patterns warning.  And it should, because the way you have defined `AorB` is "open".  That is, somebody in another module is free to declare

```
instance AorB 'C
```

and then your definition of `foo` will suddenly become invalid as it fails to handle the `SomeC` case.  To get what you are looking for, you should use a *closed type family*:

```
type family IsAorB s where
    IsAorB 'A = 'True
    IsAorB 'B = 'True
    IsAorB _  = 'False
```

This family is totally defined on `State`s.  We would then define your previous `AorB` constraint like so:

```
type AorB s = IsAorB s ~ 'True
```

However, in a moment we will need to use `AorB` in curried form, which is not allowed for type synonyms.  There is an idiom for declaring curriable synonyms which is a bit clunky, but is the best we have at the moment:

```
class    (IsAorB s ~ 'True) => AorB s
instance (IsAorB s ~ 'True) => AorB s
```

Anyway, with this new definition, you will find that the inexhaustive pattern warning goes away for `foo`.  Good.

Now on to your question.  The trouble with your definition (with an explicit `forall` added for clarity)

```
bar :: forall s. AorB s => Some s
bar = SomeA
```

is that we are allowed to instantiate `bar @B`, giving us

```
bar @B :: AorB B => Some B
bar = SomeA
```

`AorB B` is satisfiable, so we should be able to get a `Some B`, right?  But not according to your implementation.  So something is logically wrong here.  You are probably looking to return an *existentially quantified* `s`, in other words, you want the `bar` function to choose which `s` it is, not the caller.  Informally

```
bar :: exists s. AorB s <AND> Some s
```

That is, `bar` chooses an `s`, and returns a `Some s`, together with some evidence that `AorB s` holds.  This is no longer an implication, we would not put the responsibility on the caller to prove that the type `bar` chose was either `A` or `B` -- the caller has no idea what was chosen.

Haskell does not directly support existential types, but we can model them with a GADT (make sure to use `PolyKinds` and `ConstraintKinds`)

```
data Ex c f where
     Ex :: c a => f a -> Ex c f
```

`Ex c f` can be read as "there exists `a` such that `c a` holds *and* there is a value `f a`".  This is existential becuase the variable `a` does not appear in `Ex c f`, it's hidden by the constructor. And now we can implement `bar`

```
bar :: Ex AorB Some
bar = Ex SomeA
```

We can test that the constraints are correctly propagated by passing this to your `foo`:

```
test :: Bool
test = case bar of Ex s -> foo s
```

There you go.

That said, design-wise I would just say

```
bar :: Some A
```

instead.  Type signatures should be as informative as possible.  Don't hide information that you know -- let abstraction do the hiding. When you hide information about your assumptions/arguments, you are making your signature *stronger*; when you hide about your results, you are making it *weaker*.  Make it strong.

Comment: I did come up with the `IsAorB` type family, but I wouldn't get to the `AorB` and (certainly not) to the `Ex c f` tricks. Cheers!

Comment: I was thinking and experimenting with this a bit more. I tried `bar :: AorB s => Some s`, but it still cannot match the type of `s`. Shouldn't this `AorB s` (`IsAorB s ~ 'True`) constraint be enough to limit the resulting types (and not necessarily controlled by the caller)?

Comment: @ThalesMG no the caller still chooses.  The caller chooses any unquantified variable in a type signature (IOW all variables are implicitly `forall` at the top level).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full working code based on @luqui's answer, for reference:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Test2 where

data State = A | B | C

type family IsAorB (s :: State) where
  IsAorB 'A = 'True
  IsAorB 'B = 'True
  IsAorB _  = 'False

-- type AorB s = IsAorB s ~ 'True

class (IsAorB s ~ 'True) => AorB s
instance (IsAorB s ~ 'True) => AorB s

data Some (s :: State) where
  SomeA :: Some 'A
  SomeB :: Some 'B
  SomeC :: Some 'C

data Ex c f where
  Ex :: c a => f a -> Ex c f

bar :: Ex AorB Some
bar = Ex SomeA
```